# JOGL 2.0 and GLUT

Tags: java, opengl, glut, jogl

I'm trying to use GLUT. The problem is that I don't have the class "com.sun.opengl.util.*", so right now I can't use it at all.

Is there any possibility to use it JOGL with GLUT?

Comment: Why do you want to? GLUT is a cross-platform tool for creating and managing OpenGL windows. JOGL already has tools for creating and managing OpenGL windows.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I wrote why I'm using it. But I suppose it got deleted. So the reason why I'm using it is because my teacher told me so. I'm in a course which is about JOGL and right now we're using GLUT. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JOGL version your course is about probably 1, not JOGL2.

com.sun is now com.jogamp
Since JOGL is mantained by JogAmp community now, not Sun.

Comment: That was easy. Thank you for your quick answer. Now it works perfectly.